# Tycho copy-dependencies do not include plugin dependencies

Tags: maven, tycho

For one plugin in my tycho reactor I would like to copy a "pure-maven" dependency and its transitive ones in a folder named "lib/".

Currently if I use the `copy-dependencies` goal from `maven-dependency-plugin`, my dependency is correctly copied but the "plugin-dependencies" resolved by tycho are also copied, and I don't want those.

Any suggestion to achieve this goal ? I'm currently using the following code snippet

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>${maven.groupid}</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer> 
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this discussion on Eclipse forums](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg05080.html) it seems that we can tell maven to only include dependencies coming from the current `pom.xml` file using a combination of `excludeScope` and `includeScope` tags.

This updated XML snippet does the job as expected

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>${maven.groupid}</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase> 
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer> 
                        <!-- The lines below are aimed at telling maven NOT TO COPY tycho dependencies. Do not remove those! -->
                        <!-- See: https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg05080.html -->
                        <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```